# Phone input to call back after

Tags: input

I am creating a new website for my design/programming studio.
A good option is add box at the bottom of site like 
"Please leave your phone number, we call back  " ?

Or maybe it is unnecessary element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on what your audience wants.**

Sometimes potential customers will be on your website and they want to call with a question but they aren't able to call you at that moment, a tool like this is good for that. You will have to add a field where they can select when they want to be called though, nobody wants to wait an entire day for a call.

But if your potential customers aren't really the type to call, but rather chat or have e-mail contact, it might be unnecessary to use a call-me-back tool.

Comment: At 8-16 i am in other work and I can't  to pick up a call. I'can't put my phone number in website. I think that email address + phone box is the best solution.